# Blender 2.73 Objects do not respond to script, but do to Python console

Tags: python, scripting

TLDR: I can change stuff with Python in the console, but not when lumped together in a script.  What gives?

I'm trying to command an object's location and orientation by running a script in the text editor (and then saving the resulting image).  I can use Python in the embedded console to change object properties (like position and orientation), but when running these commands as a script from the text editor they will change orientation, but not position.  I need to change an object's location and orientation.  What could be causing this?

These objects exist in a .blend file that has objects, lights, textures, keyframes defining position, etc.

These scripts used to work before I updated a texture, added more lights, and restarted my computer a few times.  Those are the only changes I can think of.  Now they render and save the rendered image but don't change the object's location or orientation (yes, after adding more junk, the object call is still to the right object).

However, if I run the script line by line in the embedded Python console, it executes flawlessly.

All thoughts appreciated!  I'm stumped.

Script:

```
rel_loc = input("\nPlease input relative location of object 1, separated by spaces: x y z:  ")
rel_att = input("Please input relative attitude of object 1, separated by spaces: w x y z: ")

#split out 'words' and convert to floats
rel_loc_p = rel_loc.split()
rel_loc = []

for n in range(0,len(rel_loc_p)):
    rel_loc = rel_loc + [float(rel_loc_p[n])]

rel_att_p = rel_att.split()
rel_att = []

for n in range(0,len(rel_att_p)):
    rel_att = rel_att + [float(rel_att_p[n])]


print("relative location " + str(rel_loc))
print("relative attitude " + str(rel_att))

#set position
bpy.data.objects[1].location = rel_loc

#set attitude
bpy.data.objects[1].rotation_quaternion = rel_att

#location, rotation, and scale
#bpy.data.objects[1].matrix_world.decompose()

file_nname = input("please enter name and extension for file: ")
file_ppath = input("please enter entire save file path, use '/' instead of '\': ")

#render and save image

full_name = file_ppath+file_nname
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = full_name
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

Comment: I assume you've simply forgot to place `import bpy` at the top of the script, right?

Comment: what output you see on the console ? try printing the object name to be sure it's the right one

Comment: poor, yep, just cut the text right below that reference.  I promise it's there!

Chebhou, yes, the object is correct

(if I can only notify one previous author then I won't notify any!)

Comment: For me it works, what exactly is your issue?

Comment: @poor, thanks for the sanity check.  It seems to work for me too when I use it in a new blend file.  What could I have done to my previous one to stop it from working??

Comment: The only requirement is to select an object right?  What happens if you run the script in your current blend?

Comment: @poor, I'm not sure what you mean by current blend.  I can create a new one, add objects, and the script works fine.  I have several copies of the blend I'd like it to work in and it doesn't work in any.  What could mess this up?  Does defining key frames break the Python commanding?

Comment: keyframes, constraints, drivers will override any movement you make ,  but you said it worked through console !?

Comment: @Chebhou. yep.  Hence my confusion.  I deleted all my keyframes and it's still stuck, but now only in position.  I can use the script to change the attitude.  The 'location' section under the transform menu is green instead of grey.  Is that a problem?  What does the green mean?

Comment: @clueless green means there are other keyframes you should delete ALL KEYFRAMES

Comment: @Chebhou ahahaha you were right and now it works!  Strange, I thought it worked before with key frames.

Anyway, the moral of the story is you can't command things which are defined with keyframes from scripts, but you can with the Python console.

Thanks for the help, Chebhou and Poor!

Comment: If someone else wants to add this as an answer below I'll mark it correct

Comment: Can't see any keyframe... :)

Comment: @poor on his file he had some keyframes, that's why it was working on a fresh file

Comment: @Chebhou Thanks, I know :) But nice that you could solve the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit to @Chebhou.

From above:

"Anyway, the moral of the story is you can't command things which are defined with keyframes from scripts, but you can with the Python console."